# How to use HTML syntax in jade templates

Tags: node.js, pug

I want to focus on learning how to build things in node without having to fiddle about with the jade syntax. I want to know if its possible to blend native html syntax in jade templates along with its looping syntax etc.If so how. If not, is there a template engine for node that will allow this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at EJS? https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure you can blend plain HTML and Jade code, just use [Piped Text](http://jade-lang.com/reference/#pipedtext).
For example:

```
| <a href="#">Plain HTML</a>
```

Here an example from the [Jade Online Demo](http://jade-lang.com/demo/) (actually great to play around with and test some sort of things!):

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= pageTitle
    script(type='text/javascript').
      if (foo) {
         bar(1 + 5)
      }
  body
    h1 Jade - node template engine
    #container.col
      if youAreUsingJade
        p You are amazing
      else
        p Get on it!
      p.
        Jade is a terse and simple
        templating language with a
        strong focus on performance
        and powerful features.
    | <a href="#">Plain HTML</a>
```

with this test data:

```
{
  pageTitle: 'Jade Demo',
  youAreUsingJade: true
}
```

generates this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Jade Demo</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if (foo) {
         bar(1 + 5)
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Jade - node template engine</h1>
    <div id="container" class="col">
      <p>You are amazing</p>
      <p>
        Jade is a terse and simple
        templating language with a
        strong focus on performance
        and powerful features.
      </p>
    </div><a href="#">Plain HTML</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I thought I read something along these lines somewhere and figured someone on SO would know.

Comment: In what file is one supposed to put that "test data"? The app.js? I'm passing in the var youAreUsingJade: true but the jade template still thinks it's false.